# CSS: Prevent text from overflowing div element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and have a `div` which has long text inside it.
If the text gets to long, it overflows my `div`.

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhlAq.png).

Adding a space (resulting in shorter words) results in it looking fine.

Long words like `"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"` will cause overflow, like it did in the picture.

**My code:**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="p-1 mt-4 d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="p-1 m-1 d-flex flex-content-around shadow-lg p-2 mb-4 bg-white rounded box">
        <div class="my-auto">
            <img alt="pokemon pic" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/66.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="p-1 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-0">
                <h3>Macgoooooo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 d-flex flex-column flex-wrap">
                <div class="p-0">
                    <span>cought at</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-0">
                    <small>2019-09-01</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really like to know how to make the text fit inside the flexbox.

Comment: The code works perfectly. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: did you click the image i upload above? the text going to be outside

Comment: i've checked the code you uploaded. Everything is in the box.

Comment: on mine is not, i am using chrome, did u open my pic above ?? u can see the text Macgoooooo to be outiside its box

Answer (score 3):

The code works perfectly fine, but still if there still is issue, then you should try the following to add in your css:

```
h3{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

This will break any long words and will keep everything in multiple lines depending on the length of your word.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` <sup>*[Docs](https://cssreference.io/property/overflow-wrap/)*</sup> like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="p-1 mt-4 d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="p-1 m-1 d-flex flex-content-around shadow-lg p-2 mb-4 bg-white rounded box">
        <div class="my-auto">
            <img alt="pokemon pic" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/66.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="p-1 d-flex flex-column" style="display:inline-block; word-break: break-word;">
            <div class="p-0">
                <h3>Macgoooooo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="p-0 d-flex flex-column flex-wrap">
                <div class="p-0">
                    <span>cought at</span>
                </div>
                <div class="p-0">
                    <small>2019-09-01</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so is tha that will automatically break the word ??

Comment: it's a CSS attribute which will do the trick for you. If it helps don't forget to upvote and accept

Comment: when i tried to add that style on chrome html, it doesnt change

Comment: add another attribute like style="display:inline-block;
word-break: break-word;"

Answer (score 0):

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

for the width attribute, you need to use the width of the box